# How do I use Indesign Find/Change correctly?

Tags: adobe-indesign

My text in Indesign contains numerous instances of words followed by a comma and no space after the comma (like: "Hello,Joe"). I'd like to insert a space after the commas (corrected: "Hello, Joe"). I thought to use the Find/Change feature.

Using Find/Change I entered this in the Find dialog: "^$,^$". It finds the words with no space after a comma, as I had hoped. I thought entering "^$, ^$" in the Change field would preserve my text and add the space, but alls it does is change my text to "Hell^$, ^$oe."

How do I get this to work?

Comment: Have you looked at the “Found text” submenu in the “@” menu on the Find/Change dialog box? That should have what you’re looking for.

Comment: Janus, When I select "Found Text" the Change field changes to "$0". What do I need to do with that in order for it to add a space after the comma?

Comment: You need to set off the text you want repeated in parentheses in the _Find_ field, so you’ll have two groups of text: the one before the comma, and the one after the comma: `(^$),(^$)`. $1, $2, $3 (etc.) function as placeholders in the _Replace_ field, so you simply put them where you want the groups of text found to go in the replacement string: `$1, $2`.

Comment: Thanks for that explanation! I knew I was not getting the concept of how the Find/Change works. I'll try this and see what I can do.

Comment: Honestly, I would cheat. Replace *all* the commas with comma-space, and then do another S/R for double spaces. Very quick and no variables involved.

Answer (score 2):

I worked out the solution thanks to Janus Bahs Jacquet's comment:

Using the GREP option in Find/Change I entered "(,)([\l\u])" in the Find field. The first set of parentheses searches for a comma and the second looks for any letter, which I used because it will not match to a whitespace.

In Change I entered ", $2" which is a comma, space to be inserted, and a placeholder ("$2") that refers to "([\l\u])" in the Find field. The placeholder keeps any letter that immediately followed the comma.

Now that I get the concept, the [online documentation](https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/find-change.html) seems much clearer. Thanks!

Comment: You don't have to put the comma in parentheses—parentheses mark groups of text that you intend to use again in the replacement field (i.e., text that varies), and a comma is just a comma. So to make it even simpler, you could do just “`,(\S)`”, where `\S` is the escaped GREP character for ‘anything that is not a space character’, and then replace it with “`, $1`”.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet wouldnt it be easier just to match a forward lookup and replace by `, `

Comment: @joojaa I don't know about easier… equally easy, I'd say. (The reason I rarely do lookaheads and lookbehinds is that I somehow manage to forget the proper syntax in about 15 seconds, no matter how many times I look it up.)